# Python named pipes - running 2 apps through each other

Tags: python, synchronization, named-pipes, data-synchronization, mkfifo

Very new to python and named pipes!

I am trying to run an GUI and a motion tracking application at the same time - and send the motion tracking application output (CSV) to the GUI script to synchronise the two data streams. Using a named pipe, how do we create a connection to sync the two applications?

I have a fully functional script for the GUI and a fully functional script for the motion tracking and cannot figure out how to add a named pipe in the GUI script to obtain the motion tracking script.

Comment: Named pipes are unidirectional; you want a socket.

Comment: Will I need a bidirectional connection to feed the motion tracking output to the GUI ?

Comment: When I saw "synchronization", I assumed a two-way process where each component could update the other. If you really do need to send data only one way, a named pipe would be sufficient.

Comment: Do you know how a named pipe can be used to send between the GUI and motion-tracking script? I can make a pipe in the motion-tracking script but can't understand how to link it to the GUI

Comment: You treat it like a file. Open it for writing in one script, for reading in the other. Reads will block if the pipe is currently empty until the other writes to it; writes will block if the pipe is full until the other reads from it.

Comment: Only *one* process has to actually *create* the pipe; ideally, that's something *neither* script is responsible for, but something you create during installation so that both scripts can assume it already exists.

Comment: So I write the named pipe and then make both processes read the pipe, or just one process must read the pipe while the other writes?

Comment: I think are confusing "create the named pipe" with "write to the named pipe". They are two separate actions. For example, in shell you could write something like `mkfifo p1; command1 > p1 & command2 < p1 &`, which is somewhat the same as `command1 | command2`.

Comment: So this is writing to the named pipe? -- Sorry, I'm actually very new to Python and still trying to wrap my head around everything. Should I create the named Pipe (mkfifo) separately, then write to it from one app and read from another?

Comment: I'm curious where you got the idea that you can or should use a named pipe, given your lack of familiarity with them.

Comment: We contacted the developers of both apps, who recommended using a named pipe - which also seems to be the simplest way to feed data between the apps. Wouldn't normally attempt to do something so out of my depth!

Comment: I would *assume*, then, that you just create the fifo, then supply its name as either the input or output file to each script as appropriate.

Comment: I can create the fifo separately outside of these apps, just in the command prompt/terminal?